# Foreign key constraint with UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, foreign-keys

I recently converted my database to UTF-8, which it should have been in the first place. Everything looks fine, except when I use the function

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($_POST['province']);
```

I am getting ASCII for everything that doesn't contain special characters, and I am getting UTF-8 for everything that does. However, these values are all being pulled from the **database** itself, so this is confusing to me. Is this how it is supposed to work?

Another thing that is not working is my foreign key constraint; I am unable to enter values from a dropdown list, which is again pulling the values from the database, so.

When I use

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($_POST['province']);
echo $_POST['province'];
```

I get

```
UTF-8
Galápagos
```

Which I cannot enter into the database under the reports table due to the foreign key restraint on the province table. However, the value coming directly from province table. I am losing my mind here.

However, I get

```
ASCII
Carchi
```

For another province in Ecuador, and this value goes right into the database. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a case of needing client encoding set properly. Try this after the initial mysql connect:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")
```

Comment: Thank you :) That did it! Do I have to put this everywhere I am accessing the database? Inserting into the database? Reading from it?

Comment: Ah I see what you meant. I just put it on my connect.php page, so it reminds the client every single time. Cool, thanks 8)